# Unexpected crash on AlertDialog after menu

Tags: java, android, menu, android-alertdialog

I'm experiencing an **unexpected crash** of my emulator few seconds after an AlertDialog appears, before I can even select an option. Do you have any idea on what the problem could be?

I have a ListView with several objects. On a LongClick a **small menu** will appear. By selecting the option "Delete" I want an AlertDialog to show up and ask if the user is sure of he's doing.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.rename:
                // rename the entry in the list
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                // confirmation popup before deleting
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(R.string.app_name).setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this package?").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       // Really delete the package
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                }).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Right before the crash I get this message in the log:

> EmuGL:WARNING: bad generic pointer 0x7f64d97be818

Comment: Tested this code in my android studio, it works perfectly. I think maybe context is null or something like that.

Comment: @mesutbeyaztas maybe you are right... but what should I put in place of `getActivity()` as context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the **problem was the AVD** itself! I was using one with a **broken system image**. Downloading it again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this it maybe fix the crash.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```